# Example of interior and limit points.

Tags: general-topology

I am trying to cook up an example where $\text{Int }E\setminus E'$ and $E'\setminus \text{Int }E$ are both nonempty. I am given that $\overline{E}=\text{Int }E\cup \text{Bd }E=E'\cup \{\text{isolated points of }E\}$.

My approach to finding such an example is to find a set where there is an element that is a limit point, but is not in the interior, and an element that is in the interior, but is not a limit point. The first condition is easy. Take $[0,1]\subset \mathbb{R}$, then $0$ is a limit point, but is not in the interior of $[0,1]$. However, the other condition is proving to be difficult. I am currently attempting to find some example like $E=\{(0,\frac{1}{n}): n\in \mathbb{Z}_+\}$, $\{0\}$ is a limit point of $E$ and is not in the interior of E, but I am unsure that this will satisfy the second condition.

What would be an example of such a set? Or what hints can you provide to find an example of such a set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $a$ is an interior point but not limit point, you must make sure $\{a\}$ is open. Then you just need to construct a limit point which is not an interior ponit. Discrete topology doesn't work since there is no limit point.

For example, let $X=\{1,2,3\}$, with topology $\mathcal{T}=\{\emptyset,\{1\},\{1,2\},\{1,2,3\}\}, E=\{1,3\}$. Then $\text{int} E=\{1\},E'=\{3\}.$